# Add Event to Calendar on Button Click

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I'm new to android programming and was looking at how to create `calendars`. I was wondering if anyone could help me to add an `event` to a specific day on the `calendar` when a user `clicks` on a day. All the examples and tutorials I've seen are hard-coded `events` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Once the calendar has loaded on screen the user must be able to click on a day from the calendar and be able to add an event and save it.

Comment: Do you want to open the default calendar and add an event on that day if the button clicks ?

Comment: @SultanMahmud yes that is what I would to achieve. The user must click on a day from the calendar and be able to add an event on that day.

Comment: Follow this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-adding-events-to-the-users-calendar--mobile-8363